# SpriteKit driving techniques

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-engine, game-physics

I'm an iOS developer that wants to make a game in SpriteKit. I have zero game development experience :)

It will be a 2D game where a car drives over the horizontal axis of the screen from A to B. There will be bumps and other obstacles. I would like to apply a lot of physics, explosions, etc. The car will be impacted by them, slowing down, tossing over, etc. Also, the car might lose a wheel.

My question might sound trivial: How to make the car "drive".

Would it be possible/realistic to structure my car class in such a way that it actually has wheels, that rotate and that actually move the car forwards? The car would need certain properties to gain traction on the ground.

This would allow really for nice things like driving on different surfaces with different properties etc. (ice, dirt, tarmac)

I'm looking for best practices and techniques on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the car and the wheels as SKSpritekits all to one SKNode, gave them position in that node, and move the parent node horizontally. There are multiple way to move a node horizontally, you can do it by creating SKAction - moveTo, moveBy, move, or just by applying force, impulse, velocity parentNode.physicsBody.applyImpulse. When you move the parent node - it will move all in it. And you can give the wheels rotation of course so they will rotate,  if you use appropriate SKAction - they will rotate forever.

```
    let parentNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
    parentNode.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 100)
    addChild(parentNode)
    let car = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "car")
    let wheel1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wheel")
    let wheel2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wheel")
    wheel1.position = CGPoint(x: -110, y: -20)
    wheel2.position = CGPoint(x: 135, y: -20)
    car.position = CGPoint(x:40, y: 50)
    let spin = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -.pi*2, duration: 10)
    let spinForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spin)
    wheel1.run(spinForever)
    wheel2.run(spinForever)
    parentNode.addChild(wheel1)
    parentNode.addChild(wheel2)
    parentNode.addChild(car)
    let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 100), duration: 50)
    parentNode.run(move)
```

Keep in mind,  child node's position is with respect to its parent